# Watching folders and subfolders for file changes is not detecting changes

Tags: c++, windows, file, watch

What I want to do: monitor a given folder and all its sub-folders for any changes in their files'contents (in Windows, using C++).

What I have tried:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


void WatchFileChanges(char *dir) {

while (true)
{
    HANDLE dwChangeHandles[1];

    dwChangeHandles[0] = FindFirstChangeNotification(
        dir,                         // directory to watch 
        FALSE,                         // do not watch subtree 
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE); // watch file name changes

    auto res = WaitForSingleObject(dwChangeHandles, INFINITE);

    switch (res)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0: std::cout << "changed" << std::endl; break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT: std::cout << "time's up" << std::endl; break;
    }
}
}

int main()
{
    WatchFileChanges("D:/myfolder");
    return 0;
}
```

I run the above code and try making (and saving) changes to files that lay within the folder "D:/myfolder". However, nothing happens in my program. No message is displayed at all, while I would expect "changed" to be displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use `bWatchSubtree: TRUE`?

Comment: @Dai Nothing changes. It still does not catch any changes I make.

Comment: Many programs never change a file.  A text editor never does for example, it is far too risky.  You have to include FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME to see it rename files.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, but I am not interested in watching for changes in file names. I am interested in monitoring files having content being modified.

Comment: @HansPassant also, there has to be something else going on. Because for testing sake, I just trying using `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` instead, and changing files' names, and still the program does not detect it.

Comment: Hard to guess.  Maybe the drive doesn't support it, like a flash memory stick.  There is no error checking, you hope that everything works, so you'll never find out.  Well, the program will end quickly I guess.

Comment: Try `dwNotifyFilter: 0x11F` (the bitwise `OR` of every documented filter option).

Comment: @HansPassant That's why I cam after suggestions on, for instance, which error checking I could make to detect the issue. Any constructive suggestion will be super welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Just copy/paste the [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx), it has error checking.

Comment: @Dai You mean substituting `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` for `0x11F` for checking purposes? Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain things I do when I have problems. I often add code that writes out relevant information when things **might** go wrong; not when I expect something to go wrong, but when something **could** go wrong. So I tested your code and I **automatically** added a default to the switch. My output was **full** of output from the default case, I assume indicating failure of the WaitForSingleObject. So I noticed that you are using dwChangeHandles[0] for the result of FindFirstChangeNotification and dwChangeHandles in the WaitForSingleObject. When I changed dwChangeHandles to dwChangeHandles[0] then it worked for me.

Sometimes we overlook the simple because we expect it to be difficult.

Comment: I have to say that yes, I did try a default case to check that the `WaitForSingleObject` was indeed failing. However, I never realized that could be the reason because I was assuming that `dwChangeHandles[0]` and `dwChangeHandles` were just pointing to the same memory address. It puzzles me to understand why this is the solution to the problem, but you are very right: it was! Many thanks!

Comment: It does take time to get comfortable with pointers and redirection and all that. The alternative to `dwChangeHandles[0]` is `*dwChangeHandles`.